# Update post meta not working on wp_postmeta

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am trying to update post meta values but it does't work. Only function that is working is get_post_meta and add_post_meta but Update wont work at all. Also I tried to change the values using wpdb->update but that wont work either.

Here is the code.

```
function rating_system_callback(){

if(  !wp_verify_nonce(  $_POST['nonce'] ,'star_rating_nonce' )){
    wp_die('No nonce found.');
}
if(record_check_and_add($_POST)){
    $total_user_voted = get_post_meta( $_POST['post_id'], 'no_of_user_voted', true );


    if(empty($total_user_voted)){
        add_post_meta($_POST['post_id'], 'no_of_user_voted', 1, true);
    }
    $new_user = $total_user_voted + 1;
    update_post_meta($_POST['post-id'], 'no_of_user_voted', '58');


    if(empty($total_votes_for_post)){
        add_post_meta($_POST['post_id'], 'total_points_for_post', $_POST['clicked_on'], true);

    }
    $new_points =  $total_votes_for_post + $_POST['clicked_on'];
    update_post_meta($_POST['post-id'], 'total_points_for_post',$new_points);

    $whole_avg = round($new_points / $new_user, 1) ;

    $avg = get_post_meta($_POST['post_id'], 'whole_avg', $whole_avg, true);
    if(empty($avg)){
        add_post_meta($_POST['post_id'], 'whole_avg', $whole_avg, true);

    }
    update_post_meta($_POST['post-id'], 'whole_avg',$whole_avg);
    wp_die();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.... you could use the correct Field in the $_POST, which would be $_POST['post_id'], not $_POST['post-id'] ;)

Replace

```
update_post_meta($_POST['post-id'], 'whole_avg',$whole_avg);
```

with

```
update_post_meta($_POST['post_id'], 'whole_avg',$whole_avg);
```

etc.

;) Happy Coding,

Kuchenundkakao